# Fill one column with previous row other column

Tags: sql

Let's say that I have a table with data like this:

```
|start|stop|name
|-----|----|----
|1    |NULL|John
|5    |7   |John
|9    |13  |John
|22   |NULL|John
|34   |NULL|John
|65   |69  |John
|74   |NULL|John
```

What's the easiest way to fill the null values ('stop') with the next row's start value, like that:

```
|start|stop|name
|-----|----|----
|1    |5   |John
|5    |7   |John
|9    |13  |John
|22   |34  |John
|34   |65  |John
|65   |69  |John
|74   |NULL|John
```

Can I do it with query only? Or do I have to engage the PHP to get rows and then run multiple other smaller queries?

Comment: *Which* SQL implementation? `sql` alone is an abstract concept.

Comment: hint: use 'lead'

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your select

```
select start, case when stop is null then lead(start,1,null) over(order by start) else stop end......
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Try this query. You can do it multiple ways in SQL

```
create table #table1 (startid int, stopid int, tname varchar(20))
insert into #table1 values
 (1 ,NULL,'John')
 ,(5 ,7   ,'John')
 ,(9 ,13  ,'John')
 ,(22,NULL,'John')
 ,(34,NULL,'John')
 ,(65,69  ,'John')
 ,(74,NULL,'John')

 select * from #table1
 select t.startid, nullif(isnull(t.stopid, t.Newvalue),0)stopid
 from(
 select *,LEAD(startid, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY startid) AS Newvalue
 from #table1
 )t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()` and `coalesce()`:

```
select start,
       coalesce(stop, lead(start) over (partition by name order by start)) as stop,
       name
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't tagged any `DBMS` so, i would just use `subquery` with correlation approach

```
select start, coalesce(stop,  
              (select top 1 start from table where start > t.start and name = t.name 
                                  order by start)) as stop, 
        name
from table t;
```